# i have a DLL build in c++ which has a method that return class pointer object ,how to receive this class pointer object in my Java code

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, jna

i got dll from the customer ,this dll has methode which return class object e.g.
DLL code is like this-

```
namespace mDLL
{ 
class myDll
{
      public:
      char* getName()
      {
            return "Hello World";
      }
};
}
extern "C" _declspec(dllimport) mDLL::myDll* GetDllInstance(__in__ const        char* const Name);
```

i want to use this dll insdie my JAVA code and call methode **GetDllInstance** ,please help me in implementing this . i tried JNA but dont know how to retrieve class pointer object

Comment: Note that the only use you can make of this pointer in Java, is to send it back to C++ in some other JNI call.

Comment: In general you are going to create an interface class that extends Library and calls `Native.loadLibrary("TheDLLname", YourClassName.class);` and then define that method with `String` argument. The return value depends on what you're going to do with it and/or the DLL.  At a minimum it will be a `Pointer`.   More likely you'll want a `PointerByReference`. Will you be calling other methods of that DLL?  Please tell us what further action you want to take with the returned class pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion of a string (char *) parameter in your `GetDllInstance` method is undocumented in your question.  I am answering under the assumption that you would pass the name of the DLL as an argument here, e.g., "MyDll".  If this assumption is incorrect, please comment and I will update this answer.

You will begin by creating an interface for the DLL that extends [JNA's Library interface](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Library.html), inside which you specify the signature of the API's methods

```
public interface MyDll extends Library {
    MyDLL INSTANCE = (MyDLL) Native.loadLibrary("MyDll", MyDll.class);

    String getName();
}
```

Following this, you can access the method of this DLL simply within your code by calling the instance:

```
String name = MyDll.INSTANCE.getName();
```

There is no need for you to keep track of the pointer to the DLL instance; by inheriting from JNA's `Library` class all that work is done for you by JNA.